# Show gvim scrollbar only when needed

Tags: gvim, scrollbar

Gvim has a default behavior where it always shows a scrollbar on all buffers at all times.

Is there a way to make the scrollbar visible only if the document is larger than the frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in one of your startup files, `~/.vimrc`, `~/.gvimrc`, `~/_vimrc` or `~/_gvimrc`, to add or remove the right scrollbar option (`r`) from `guioptions` (abbreviated `go`).

```
au VimEnter * if line('$') > &lines | set go+=r | else | set go-=r | endif
au VimResized * if line('$') > &lines | set go+=r | else | set go-=r | endif
```

Those autocommands don't cover all the events that might cause the buffer size to exceed the window size, but it gives you the idea. See

```
:help autocommand-events
```

for more.